# spring urlrewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter` to rewrite, but

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^/ms-office$</from>
        <to>/office</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/ms-office/(^[0-9]+$)</from>
        <to>/office/eidt?id=$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

when I entry to `ms-office/10` a get `WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/s-mvc/ms-office/10] in DispatcherServlet with name 'config'`

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Spring, but it looks like you have a typo in your <to> element.  I assume that should read: /office/edit/id=$1

Comment: Is the second `from` should match `/ms-office/10` or `/whatever/ms-office/10`? If the first one then you missed `^` anchor as in the first rule.

Comment: @Tom make this comment an anwser so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second `from` should match `/ms-office/10` then you missed `^` anchor as in the first rule.